# Handy way to index set of tuples in AMPL

Tags: optimization, graphs, ampl

I am dealing with a discrete math optimization problem on a complete graph. My variables are the arcs but I want to delete the arcs that "cost too much". I have $n$ nodes which means I have $n(n-1)$ arcs before deletion.
I define the following set in AMPL

```
ARCS:={i in 1..n, j in 1..n : i!=j && d[i,j]<= R}
```

where `d[i,j]` is the cost on the arc `(i,j)` and `R` the limit I am putting.

My problem is that I don't know how to index the variables now. I know I can write

`sum{ i in 1..n, j in 1..n : (i,j) in ARCS} blablabla[i,j]`

But I think this is quite a tedious way to do.
I thought I could write something like this
 `sum{e in ARCS} blablabla[e[0],e[1]]`

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
sum{(i,j) in ARCS} blablabla[i,j]
```